# the Convergent of this serie $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} U_{n}$ Convergent knowing that :

$U_{n}=\sin \left ( \frac{n}{n^{2}+1} \right )$

I tried the comparison method which led me to :
$0\leq U_{n}\leq \frac{1}{n}$

but $\frac{1}{n^{p}}$ is unkown because $p=1$ 
what's another method please ?

Comment: I would use the limit-comparison test.

Comment: The harmonic series is divergent, hence the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\sin\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ is divergent as well, by asymptotic comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x\to 0$, we have $\sin(x) \sim x$. Thus $$\sin\left(\frac n{n^2+1}\right) \sim \frac n{n^2+1} \sim \frac 1 n$$ as $n \to \infty$ so the series diverges since the harmonic series diverges.